Trouble making chrome extension
I'm experiencing an issue while trying to add a Google Chrome extension from VS Code. When I click "Load unpacked" and attempt to load the folder containing my code, the folder appears empty. This results in an error stating:
Required value 'version' is missing or invalid. It must be between 1-4 dot-separated integers each between 0 and 65536. Could not load manifest.

Image #1
Image #2
Actual content of file:
Image #3
Manifest.josn
{
    "manifest_version":3,
    "name": "crypto tracker", 
    "Version": "1.0",
    "Description": "track cryptocurrenct prices",
    "action":{
        "defualt_pop_up":"popup.html"
    },
    "permissions":[
        "activeTab",
        "scripting"
    ]
}


Since you didn't show your manifest.json I guess you either indicated the wrong folder or manifest.json is missing "version" field. Note that the folder picker dialog won't show any files by design.

I just edited the post that includes the actual content of the folder with the manifest.json included, check image #3 and tell me what you think, I'm a novice, please bare with me

You didn't add the contents of manifest.json.

Can you elaborate please? like what do i need to do for the contents of manifest.json to be considered "added"

Please add the contents of manifest.json into the question. Open the file, select its contents, copy it and paste into the question.

I've gone ahead and done what you've asked thank you!

Use lowercase letters v in version and d in description, also fix your default_popup.

I've made  the changes but its still not letting me :(

Should i move it to a different file?
